# How do i change default orientation in infovis spacetree?

Tags: javascript, visualization, infovis, thejit, space-tree

I'm trying to change the default orientation in a space tree but can't figure out where to add:

```
st.switchPosition("top", "animate", {  
 onComplete: function() {  
   alert('completed!');  
 }  
});
```

So that the tree will start from the top instead of the default of right.

In the examples i've seen, the switchPosition is only used with an event handler, which i do not intend to have.

So in the example (taken from the infovis site:[Infovis - spacetree](http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html) ), where should i add the code (or any code) in order to change the default orientation?

var labelType, useGradients, nativeTextSupport, animate;

```
(function() {
  var ua = navigator.userAgent,
      iStuff = ua.match(/iPhone/i) || ua.match(/iPad/i),
      typeOfCanvas = typeof HTMLCanvasElement,
      nativeCanvasSupport = (typeOfCanvas == 'object' || typeOfCanvas == 'function'),
      textSupport = nativeCanvasSupport 
        && (typeof document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d').fillText == 'function');
  //I'm setting this based on the fact that ExCanvas provides text support for IE
  //and that as of today iPhone/iPad current text support is lame
  labelType = (!nativeCanvasSupport || (textSupport && !iStuff))? 'Native' : 'HTML';
  nativeTextSupport = labelType == 'Native';
  useGradients = nativeCanvasSupport;
  animate = !(iStuff || !nativeCanvasSupport);
})();

var Log = {
  elem: false,
  write: function(text){
    if (!this.elem) 
      this.elem = document.getElementById('log');
    this.elem.innerHTML = text;
    this.elem.style.left = (500 - this.elem.offsetWidth / 2) + 'px';
  }
};


function init(){
    //init data
    var json = {....removed due to space here in the group....}
    //end

    //A client-side tree generator
    var getTree = (function() {
        var i = 0;
        return function(nodeId, level) {
          var subtree = eval('(' + json.replace(/id:\"([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\"/g, 
          function(all, match) {
            return "id:\"" + match + "_" + i + "\""  
          }) + ')');
          $jit.json.prune(subtree, level); i++;
          return {
              'id': nodeId,
              'children': subtree.children
          };
        };
    })();

    //Implement a node rendering function called 'nodeline' that plots a straight line
    //when contracting or expanding a subtree.
    $jit.ST.Plot.NodeTypes.implement({
        'nodeline': {
          'render': function(node, canvas, animating) {
                if(animating === 'expand' || animating === 'contract') {
                  var pos = node.pos.getc(true), nconfig = this.node, data = node.data;
                  var width  = nconfig.width, height = nconfig.height;
                  var algnPos = this.getAlignedPos(pos, width, height);
                  var ctx = canvas.getCtx(), ort = this.config.orientation;
                  ctx.beginPath();
                  if(ort == 'left' || ort == 'right') {
                      ctx.moveTo(algnPos.x, algnPos.y + height / 2);
                      ctx.lineTo(algnPos.x + width, algnPos.y + height / 2);
                  } else {
                      ctx.moveTo(algnPos.x + width / 2, algnPos.y);
                      ctx.lineTo(algnPos.x + width / 2, algnPos.y + height);
                  }
                  ctx.stroke();
              } 
          }
        }

    });

    //init Spacetree
    //Create a new ST instance
    var st = new $jit.ST({
        'injectInto': 'infovis',
        //set duration for the animation
        duration: 800,
        //set animation transition type
        transition: $jit.Trans.Quart.easeInOut,
        //set distance between node and its children
        levelDistance: 50,
        //set max levels to show. Useful when used with
        //the request method for requesting trees of specific depth
        levelsToShow: 2,
        //set node and edge styles
        //set overridable=true for styling individual
        //nodes or edges
        Node: {
            height: 20,
            width: 40,
            //use a custom
            //node rendering function
            type: 'nodeline',
            color:'#23A4FF',
            lineWidth: 2,
            align:"center",
            overridable: true
        },

        Edge: {
            type: 'bezier',
            lineWidth: 2,
            color:'#23A4FF',
            overridable: true
        },

        //Add a request method for requesting on-demand json trees. 
        //This method gets called when a node
        //is clicked and its subtree has a smaller depth
        //than the one specified by the levelsToShow parameter.
        //In that case a subtree is requested and is added to the dataset.
        //This method is asynchronous, so you can make an Ajax request for that
        //subtree and then handle it to the onComplete callback.
        //Here we just use a client-side tree generator (the getTree function).
        request: function(nodeId, level, onComplete) {
          var ans = getTree(nodeId, level);
          onComplete.onComplete(nodeId, ans);  
        },

        onBeforeCompute: function(node){
            Log.write("loading " + node.name);
        },

        onAfterCompute: function(){
            Log.write("done");
        },

        //This method is called on DOM label creation.
        //Use this method to add event handlers and styles to
        //your node.
        onCreateLabel: function(label, node){
            label.id = node.id;            
            label.innerHTML = node.name;
            label.onclick = function(){
                st.onClick(node.id);
            };
            //set label styles
            var style = label.style;
            style.width = 40 + 'px';
            style.height = 17 + 'px';            
            style.cursor = 'pointer';
            style.color = '#fff';
            //style.backgroundColor = '#1a1a1a';
            style.fontSize = '0.8em';
            style.textAlign= 'center';
            style.textDecoration = 'underline';
            style.paddingTop = '3px';
        },

        //This method is called right before plotting
        //a node. It's useful for changing an individual node
        //style properties before plotting it.
        //The data properties prefixed with a dollar
        //sign will override the global node style properties.
        onBeforePlotNode: function(node){
            //add some color to the nodes in the path between the
            //root node and the selected node.
            if (node.selected) {
                node.data.$color = "#ff7";
            }
            else {
                delete node.data.$color;
            }
        },

        //This method is called right before plotting
        //an edge. It's useful for changing an individual edge
        //style properties before plotting it.
        //Edge data proprties prefixed with a dollar sign will
        //override the Edge global style properties.
        onBeforePlotLine: function(adj){
            if (adj.nodeFrom.selected && adj.nodeTo.selected) {
                adj.data.$color = "#eed";
                adj.data.$lineWidth = 3;
            }
            else {
                delete adj.data.$color;
                delete adj.data.$lineWidth;
            }
        }
    });
    //load json data
    st.loadJSON(eval( '(' + json + ')' ));
    //compute node positions and layout
    st.compute();
    //emulate a click on the root node.
    st.onClick(st.root);
    //end


    //Add event handlers to switch spacetree orientation. - Which i do not want...

   // function get(id) {
   //    return document.getElementById(id);  
   //  };

   //  var top = get('r-top'), 
   //  left = get('r-left'), 
   //  bottom = get('r-bottom'), 
   //  right = get('r-right');

   //  function changeHandler() {
   //      if(this.checked) {
   //          top.disabled = bottom.disabled = right.disabled = left.disabled = true;
   //          st.switchPosition(this.value, "animate", {
   //              onComplete: function(){
   //                  top.disabled = bottom.disabled = right.disabled = left.disabled = false;
   //              }
   //          });
   //      }
   //  };

   //  top.onchange = left.onchange = bottom.onchange = right.onchange = changeHandler;
    //end

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can drop in *orientation:'top',* shortly into the *new $jit.ST* function, ie:

```
    var st = new $jit.ST({  
    //id of viz container element  
    injectInto: 'infovis',  

    //SET THE TREE TO VERTICAL
    orientation:"top",

    //set duration for the animation  
    duration: 800,
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/javascript-information-visualization-toolkit/top/javascript-information-visualization-toolkit/MhXSXJUmaIk/V5JNwSe359gJ